# Bash Regex: Search for a maximum of 3 consecutive vowels

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am trying to Search for a maximum of 3 consecutive vowels

I tried

```
grep -E "([AEIOUaeiou]{3})" gpl3.txt
```

and got the results

[image]

What I want is to NOT get the (**aaaaaaaaa**) that you see in the first line of output. All other output is correct.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't post a screenshot, post text and format it using markdown.

Comment: Do you just want o skip `aaaaaaaaa` or any other 4+ occurrences of vowels?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sorry it just occured to me that I should have left the search file as text.
anubhava I want to skip ALL 4 and 4+ occurrences of vowels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all occurrences of exactly three vowels (no more, no less), then you can try this pattern:

```
grep -iP '(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{3}(?![aeiou])'
```

Using option `-P` makes `grep` use the Perl library for regular expressions which is more feature-rich than the standard regexp library.  For instance, it knows the patterns `(?<!something)` `(?!something)` which mean "must not be preceded by *something*" and "must not be followed by *something*", respectively.  Using this I express the following:

»Find stuff which is three vowels long and not preceded by a vowel and not followed by a vowel.«  This is another way of saying »exactly three vowels long«.

Concerning portability:  Using this you need to use a `grep` which is capable of using Perl regular expressions.  Today I guess this won't be an issue but if you happen to code for historical machines, you need to check this first.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works! 
I still havent learnt what -P and ?< does but I will research it. I just checked -P and it says its to do with perl. Any chance I can do without it

Comment: So `-P` is indeed Perl mode for `grep`, but it doesn't rely on having Perl installed. `grep -P` uses the `pcre` library directly, so no worries about pulling in stuff you don't need.

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys again but what does < and ! do here? I have tried searching for a tutorial and havent got anywhere after checking so many articles

Comment: @MichaelHilburt I added some explanations to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid the `-P` option and lookaheads, you can use something like the following.

```
grep -iE '(^|[^aeiou])[aeiou]{3}([^aeiou]|$)' gpl3.txt
```

It just matches

- the start of the line or a non-vowel
- three vowels
- a non-vowel or the end of the line

A test run:

```
IT070137 ~/tmp $ cat gpl3.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
asdaiosd
aa
aaa
aaaa
this is a righteous queue
IT070137 ~/tmp $ grep -E '(^|[^aeiou])[aeiou]{3}([^aeiou]|$)' gpl3.txt
asdaiosd
aaa
this is a righteous queue
```

Comment: Downvote for having `IE` in an answer to a unix question — just kidding.  This also solves the Q.

Comment: @Jon Thanks so much for your help! sorry ignore my previous comment :) - edited

Answer (score 2):

Try using a negative lookahead which asserts that *four* or more vowels do not appear consecutively:

```
grep -P "^(?!.*[AEIOUaeiou]{4,}).*$" gpl3.txt
```

We need to run this in Perl mode to use negative lookaheads.

### Demo

Comment: If you want to use a lookahead, you have to use the -P switch (if available).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I am confident of the pattern, not all confident that this would actually run on his bash.

Comment: Actually it's more a `grep` question than a `bash` question.  I added the tag.

Comment: @Alfe Then I guess there's no reason to be `bash`ful here :-)

Comment: Yes - sorry about the mistake guys. it should be a regex grep question